# Use property getters and setters with item assignment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am working on a class that is supposed to update members whenever one specific member is set. A simple example where `_bar2` is updated when `_bar1` is changed:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._bar1 = args[0]
        self._bar2 = args[1]

    @property
    def bar1(self):
        return self._bar1

    @bar1.setter
    def bar1(self, val):
        self._bar1 = val
        self._bar2 += self._bar1
```

But what if the type of`_bar1` (and possibly `_bar2` as well) supports item assignment (e.g. NumPy-arrays) and only some items shall be changed? In other words, how can I change the code to make this work:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(3)
c = foo(a, 2)
c.bar1[0] = 1.
```

So far, I have only found the package `indexedproperty` which can be installed via pip and seems to do exactly what I want. However, for several reasons I don't want the library to require a "non-standard"-package? Does anyone know another way?
So I would like to achieve exactly this:

```
class foo:
# (...)
    def set_bar1(self, idx, val):
        self._bar1[idx] = val
        self._bar2 += self._bar1
# (...)
c.set_bar1(2, 3.)
```

but with direct item assignment, i.e.

```
c.bar1[2] = 3.
```

Comment: Your class is not involved at all when mutating a value retrieved from a property.  To make this work, you'd have to write a getter that returns a wrapped version of the value, with overridden methods to apply changes to the original object when the value is mutated.

Comment: The class should probably not expose its implementation details. Instead of setting `c.bar1[0]`, you'd want to be setting `c[0]`.

Comment: @jasonharper If I understand you correctly I would have to make ``foo`` or my instance of ``foo`` known to the type of ``_bar1`` or the wrapper and change the object from some other class. Or perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: @deceze I thought about that. But my class already has a ``__getitem__`` method that mutates another array-like member. I think the ``__setitem__`` method should be consistent with that.